# The usage of know

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I want to know if the usage of the word "know" in this sentence is correct:

> They stand against annoying activities of the enemies, until God knows them as the examples of resistance and patience.

The intended meaning is that we should stand against the hardships that the enemies caused us, if we do that, we will be a paragon, a model of resistance.

Comment: What is the sentence supposed to mean?

Comment: it wants to say we should stand against the hardships that the enemies caused us, if we do that, we will be a paragon, a model of resistance.

Comment: Sounds like God sees them or recognizes them as saintly.

Answer (score 0):

God can know you when you die.

"Kill them all, God will know His own"

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massacre_at_B%C3%A9ziers

The context - standing against enemies - suggests death to me. 
The usage of "know" is correct but the meaning may be unclear.

Comment: I don't think that use of "know" implies that God only knows someone when they die. Just that dying happens to bring them to God's consideration, at which time he'll make a decision based on what he knows about them.